# java code not exporting buffered Image in correct size

Tags: java, bufferedimage, drawimage, gettype

My java code below's goal is to export a image in a 400 X 400 format. Right now the code does export a image. However it exports the image in its original size. I don't know why it does not export in its desired format. There are no errors present. The goal is just to some how get line

```
BufferedImage scaledButtonImage = new BufferedImage(400, 400, bimg.getType());
```

to work in its way.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class ren {
    Frame f;
    JLabel b2 = new JLabel("");

    ren() throws IOException {
        f = new JFrame();
        b2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Users/johnzalubski/Desktop/dropIn/Complete-Audi-Buying-Guide-gear-patrol-lead-full.jpg"));

        JButton b3 = new JButton("Exported");

        File file = new File("aa.png");

        f.add(b2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.add(b3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        f.setSize(400, 500);
        f.setVisible(true);

        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Icon ico = b2.getIcon();
                // Create a buffered image
                BufferedImage bimg = new BufferedImage(ico.getIconWidth(), ico.getIconHeight(),
                        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                // Create the graphics context
                Graphics g = bimg.createGraphics();
                // Now paint the icon
                ico.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);
                g.dispose();

                BufferedImage scaledButtonImage =
                        new BufferedImage(400, 400, bimg.getType());
                Graphics g1 = scaledButtonImage.createGraphics();
                g1.drawImage(scaledButtonImage, 0, 0, 400, 400, null);
                //                  
                g1.dispose();

                b2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bimg));
                try {
                    ImageIO.write(bimg, "png", file);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new ren();
    }
}
```

Comment: `new BufferedImage(400, 1000, bimg.getType());`, why not `400, 400`?

Comment: your right its a mistake but even if i do 400 x 400 same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a scaled version of `bimg` in `scaledButtonImage` then this line:

```
g1.drawImage(scaledButtonImage, 0, 0, 400, 400, null);
```

should be:

```
g1.drawImage(bimg, 0, 0, scaledButtonImage.getWidth(), scaledButtonImage.getHeight(),
                   0, 0, bimg.getWidth(), bimg.getHeight() null);
```

Currently your code is drawing `scaledButtonImage` into itself. Also, if you want to get a scaled copy of `bimg` you have to use the version of `drawImage` that lets you specifiy the destination and source rectangles.

Finally, you need to write out the `scaledButtonImage`, not `bimg`. Change this line

```
ImageIO.write(bimg, "png",file);
```

to

```
ImageIO.write(scaledButtonImage, "png",file);
```

Comment: I followed your instructions changed it. Same thing is happening. The image is not be exported in a 400 X 400 image.